# Чат между интернет-пользователями c#

Tags: c#, чат, nat

Каким образом реализовать соединение между интернет-пользователями как у Skype, uTorrent, TemViewer, Hamachi и другие?

(Они работают при любых ситуациях - несмотря на то, что сеть за натом и т.д.)

Answer (score 2):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relay_NAT

Вот OpenSource реализация STUN сервера под Win и Linux: http://www.stunprotocol.org/

Вот пример STUN клиента на C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18492/STUN-Client